# Use Table-Per-Type for all EF context classes with Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, fluent-interface

Currently, if I want to use Fluent API to stipulate the table-per-type inheritance strategy, I have to do the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
modelBuilder.Entity<ContentItem>().ToTable("ContentItem");
modelBuilder.Entity<MarketItem>().ToTable("MarketItem");
```

If I somehow forget to add a command for a new inherited entity it will break my schema.

What I would like to do, in pseudo code, is:

```
foreach (ModelType T in AllModelTypes)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<T>().Table(T.ToString());
}
```

Is there anything built-in to EF Fluent API that accomplishes this?

If not, is there a way I can achieve the foreach loop as described above (iterating over types?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Entity Framework 6 this should do what you want:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);    
        modelBuilder.Types().Configure(t =>t.ToTable(t.ClrType.Name));
    }
```

### Update

Here's a link to a msdn article on [Custom Code First Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx)

Comment: added a link in my answer to MSDN article on Custom Code First Conventions